# MT4 export script

Tags: export, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

The following `MQL4` script exports data from MetaTrader to a `csv` file.  Unfortunately ( for me at least ), the order of the data in the generated `csv` file from 0 to 1000, 0 being the most recent ( present to past ).  I want the file to be sorted from 1000 to 0  ( past to present ).

I altered the write data loop below to: `for (int bar=Export_Bars; bar==0 bar--)` but this simply generated an empty `csv` file.

```
#property script_show_inputs

input string    Export_FileName = "data\\data.csv"; 
input int       Export_Bars     = 20000; 
input int       StartHour = 10;
input int       EndHour = 19;

void OnStart()   
{
    int file = FileOpen(Export_FileName, FILE_WRITE|FILE_CSV|FILE_ANSI, ',');
    if (file != INVALID_HANDLE && (Hour() >= StartHour) && Hour() < EndHour)
    {
        // Write the header of data

        string row="";
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
        {
            if (StringLen(row)) 
                row += ",";
            row += "Open"+i+",High"+i+",Low"+i+",Close"+i;
        }
        FileWrite(file, row);

        // Copy all required information from the history

        MqlRates rates[], rate;
        int count = Export_Bars + 5;
        if (CopyRates(Symbol(), Period(), 1, count, rates) < count)
        {
            Print("Error! Not enough history size for exporting required information.");
            return;
        }
        ArraySetAsSeries(rates, true);

        // Write data      

        for (int bar=0; bar<Export_Bars; bar++)
        {
            row="";
            double zlevel=0;
            for (int y=0; y<=5; y++)
            {
                if (StringLen(row)) 
                    row += ",";
                rate = rates[bar+y];
                if (y==0) 
                    zlevel = rate.open; // level of price calculation
                row += NormalizeDouble(rate.open -zlevel, Digits()) + ","
                       + NormalizeDouble(rate.high -zlevel, Digits()) + ","
                       + NormalizeDouble(rate.low  -zlevel, Digits()) + ","
                       + NormalizeDouble(rate.close-zlevel, Digits());
            }
            FileWrite(file, row);
        }

        FileClose(file);
        Print("Export of data is finished successfully.");
    } else Print("Error! Failed to create the file for data export. ", GetLastError());
}
```

So my question what changes need to be made to the script in order to export data in the past to present order?

Comment: Your attempt to generate `.CSV` via a pre-condition of **`bar==0`** shall have generated one-line in `csv` output. **The loop is to run exactly once.** Check  your output processing logic why your output had remained, as objected, empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the Loop Constructor for a Time-Reverse-Iterator stepping:

```
 for ( int bar  = Export_Bars - 1;        // .LOOP-INIT(s)
           bar >= 0;                      // .LOOP-RUN-PRE-CONDITION
           bar--                          // .LOOP-RUN-POST-UPDATE(s)
       ) {...}                            // .LOOP-RUN-BODY
```

Comment: Your logic shall also somehow cope with corner cases. I.e. when your MT4.History does not contain as much as 20000 candles in DB.POOL and your blind-pointer handling will crash due to missing records (beyond the depth of the time-indexed history ). MT4 has a built-in variable / mechanics for doing this "clean".